# What started the flood in Sumerian Mythology?

Tags: sumerian, creation, flood-myth

This version of the great flood myth, I have found, is unique because it does not appear as if the gods started it or caused it. Just that they knew of it and didn't warn or try to save the humans.

> ...we learn that the gods have decided not to save mankind from an impending flood.

[Quoted from here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumerian_creation_myth#Summary)

What started the flood if the gods were not the reason?

Comment: I had to downvote because you do not cite the source of the quote "...we learn that the gods have decided not to save mankind from an impending flood."  Add the citation and I will change my vote.

Comment: Related: [What caused the Deluge?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/what-caused-the-deluge)

Comment: Re: Gibet's comment -- that's why I was mentioning the importance of citation, even if the sentence comes from the wiki.  (Otherwise, this question is unreliable.)

Answer (score 5):

It is not known because the relevant part of the Sumerian version of the myth is missing, but in later versions the cause is the god Enlil.

From an article in Livius.org: [The Great Flood: Sumerian version](http://www.livius.org/articles/misc/great-flood/flood2/).

> The story survives on a cuneiform tablet from the seventeenth century
>   BCE, of which only the lower third survives. However, this is
>   sufficient to establish that the pattern described above was already
>   present. However, there are small differences. The Eridu Genesis must
>   have begun with the Creation of Man, but continues with the
>   establishment of kingship and a list of cities. Then comes the list of
>   antediluvian rulers, which confirms the pattern again, and **the supreme
>   god Enlil's decision to destroy mankind.** The reason was recorded on a
>   missing part of the text, but may have been the noise men created, as
>   it is in the later, Babylonian texts.

From the Wikipedia article about [Enlil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlil):

> Enlil plays a vital role in the Sumerian creation myth; he separates
>   An (heaven) from Ki (earth), thus making the world habitable for
>   humans. In the Sumerian Flood myth, Enlil rewards Ziusudra with
>   immortality for having survived the flood and, **in the Babylonian flood
>   myth, Enlil is the cause of the flood himself, having sent the flood
>   to exterminate the human race,** who made too much noise and prevented
>   him from sleeping.

In the same Wikipedia article, under the [Flood Myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlil#Flood_myth) section:

> **In the Sumerian version of the flood story, the causes of the flood are unclear because the portion of the tablet recording the beginning
>   of the story has been destroyed.** Somehow, a mortal known as Ziusudra
>   manages to survive the flood, likely through the help of the god Enki.
>   The tablet begins in the middle of the description of the flood. The
>   flood lasts for seven days and seven nights before it subsides. Then,
>   Utu, the god of the Sun, emerges. Ziusudra opens a window in the side
>   of the boat and falls down prostrate before the god. Next, he
>   sacrifices an ox and a sheep in honor of Utu. At this point, the text
>   breaks off again. When it picks back up, Enlil and An are in the midst
>   of declaring Ziusudra immortal as an honor for having managed to
>   survive the flood. The remaining portion of the tablet after this
>   point is destroyed.
>
> **In the later Akkadian version of the flood story, recorded in the Epic of Gilgamesh, Enlil actually causes the flood, seeking to
>   annihilate every living thing on earth because the humans, who are
>   vastly overpopulated, make too much noise and prevent him from
>   sleeping.** In this version of the story, the hero is Utnapishtim, who
>   is warned ahead of time by Ea, the Babylonian equivalent of Enki, that
>   the flood is coming. The flood lasts for seven days; when it ends,
>   Ishtar, who had mourned the destruction of humanity, promises
>   Utnapishtim that Enlil will never cause a flood again. When Enlil sees
>   that Utnapishtim and his family have survived, he is outraged, but his
>   son Ninurta speaks up in favor of humanity, arguing that, instead of
>   causing floods, Enlil should simply ensure that humans never become
>   overpopulated by reducing their numbers using wild animals and
>   famines. Enlil goes into the boat; Utnapishtim and his wife bow before
>   him. Enlil, now appeased, grants Utnapishtim immortality as a reward
>   for his loyalty to the gods.